# What's so terrible about this naming question?

Tags: support, closed-questions, deleted-questions

[What's the name of the antipattern opposite to “reinventing the wheel”? [on hold]](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/347328/whats-the-name-of-the-antipattern-opposite-to-reinventing-the-wheel)

Many people tried suggestions of various derivatives - consequences, special cases, but none for the thing provided, or trying to invent new ones, but it appears no commonly agreed-upon name for it exists, and I accepted an answer that stated so.

The name, or lack of it, is an objective fact. There's no opinion involved. Either you give an answer citing some source, or after spending a lot of time in IT and never encountering it, you state there is no such name.

As the first comment, I asked the close-voter to say what's so opinion based, then. I never got an answer, just another four close-votes for the same reason. And now there's one "Delete" vote. What's so loathsome about this question? What did I do wrong? Where did I violate the ToS of StackExchange?

Answer (score 1):

We have [a Help Center article on the types of questions that should not be asked here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask):

> every answer is equally valid: “What’s your favorite ______?”

There are 15 undeleted answers. You accepted one a net score of 7. But there are also answers with net scores of 48, 34, 17, 13. As of now, there are 10 positively scored answers. It doesn't appear like it's possible for the community to normalize on an answer that is the right answer to the question and several are equally valid or good.

> there is no actual problem to be solved: “I’m curious if other people feel like I do.”

It's not clear to me what problem you are trying to solve. We have a list of [things that are on-topic](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center: methods and practices, requirements, architecture, design, quality assurance, testing, configuration management, builds, deployments, and releases. I don't see how you have a problem regarding any of these things.

You may have a communication problem. But that's not something that falls within our scope. We all know that naming things is hard. I can point to many examples of lack of terminology in software engineering - just take a look at the [SEI's collections (yes, there are 4 collections) of definitions of "software architecture"](http://www.sei.cmu.edu/architecture/start/glossary/definition-form.cfm).

> you are asking an open-ended, hypothetical question: “What if ______ happened?”

This may not have been your intention, but people are giving examples of words and phrases that they think are best, not providing a definition. Consider that [yes/no questions are not a good fit for the Stack Exchange format](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/183177/question-closed-because-yes-no-answer). Questions should be able to explain how or why. Because there isn't a fact or reference based answer to your question, it's driving people to post their own opinions.

Comment: The accepted answer only appeared after over a day and the question was asked a couple hours later so it didn't get to advance far. Since my question was very precise: a **common** name. I DIDN'T ASK TO INVENT ONE. The high-score answers tried to play a guessing game trying to invent alternatives or adapt similar but not matching terms, they were not valid. The actual problem is I see this antipattern commonly (as do many others) and I want to refer to it by a name instead of trying to describe its nature every time I point it out.

Comment: Once again, my question was very precise, unambiguous and not open-ended. Not my fault people jumped the gun and tried inventing new names without reading the details of what I requested.

Comment: Additionally, in my opinion this falls under "design" topic - design patterns, and design antipatterns seem to be on-topic. Names of these are commonly used. It's a pretty standard "recognize object X by description, provide name" question for which Q&A sites are excellent. In this case the object is an antipattern, which falls under the subject of design.